# Any continuous function on a proper compact set $K$ of the unit circle can be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact proper subset of the unit circle. Show that if $f$ is continuous on $K$, then it can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. The tool comes to my mind is Rung's Theorem, but I am not sure whether my direction is right or wrong. Any comments?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Probably I missed something but how would you apply Runge's theorem in this case if the function is just continuous?

Comment: @Jake28 No, I was being stupid - thx.

Comment: I don't see an extremely simple proof; as pointed out, you can't use Runge because $f$ is not holomorphic in a neighborhood of $K$. The result _is_ just a special case of Mergelyan's theorem, since $K$ does not separate the plane and has empty interior. Probably there's something more elementary...

Comment: DavidC.Ullrich and Jake28 I am sorry that I missed the conservation. BTW, that is why I am suspecting my direction may be wrong because I can't find an elementary way to show that $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $K$.

Comment: The result is definitely true. It really is just a special case of Mergelyan's theorem; also someone has posted a more elementary argument...

Answer (score 1):

Without the heavy-duty machinery of Mergelyan (which as noted by @David implies the result), one can argue like this (where $\mathbb T$ is the unit circle):

Let $A_K$ the uniform closure in $C_K$ of the functions in $A$ (where $A$ is the algebra of functions that are analytic in the open disc and continuous on the boundary); it is enough to show that $f(z)=\bar z=1/z$ belongs to $A_K$ as that implies that $A_K=C_K$ so we are done since polynomials are trivially dense in $A$, hence they will be dense in $A_K=C_K$

($\bar z \in A_K$ means that all trigonometric polynomials are in $A_K$ so by using Caesaro means say, $A_K=C_K$ since any function in $C_K$ has continuous extensions to $\mathbb T$ by general topology)

But $\mathbb T - K$ contains a non-trivial open set in $\mathbb T$ hence an arc of the unit circle and by a rotation, we can assume that arc is $|\theta| < \delta$; also, if $R>1$, $1/(z-R) \in A_K$ since it is clearly in $A$, so one can define $c =\inf {x \in \mathbb R, x>-1, 1/(z-c) \in A_K}$; if one can prove $c<0$ (for example $c=-1$), it folows $1/(z-0)=\bar z \in A_K$ so we are done by the above!

Hence let's assume $c >-1$, then there is $a>c, \epsilon >0, a-c < \epsilon$ and $K \cap |z-a| < \epsilon = \emptyset$ (here we use the hypothesis on $K$ for $a$ near $1$ as well as $c>-1$ so $a$ is away from the other real point of the unit circle, hence away from $K$ too), while $1/(z-a) \in A_K$ by the definition of $c$.

But now let $w=1/(z-a), z=\frac{1}{w}+a$ so $K \subset |z-a| \ge \epsilon$ hence $K$ lies in the disc $|w| \le 1/\epsilon$. If $|t-a| < \epsilon, 1/(z-t)=1/(1/w+(a-t))$ is obviously analytic on $|w| \le 1/\epsilon$, hence it is approximable by polynomials in $w=1/(z-a)$ there, hence on $K$; but by our choices $w=1/(z-a)$ is in $A_K$, hence polynomials in it are in $A_K$ hence $1/(z-t) \in A_K$.

Picking $t_0=\frac{a+c-\epsilon}{2}$ one has $|a-t_0| < \frac{a-c+\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon, t_0<c, 1/(z-t) \in A_K, t<t_0<a$ so contradicting the defintion of $c$ and we are finally done!